# How to spin the logo 360 degrees using CSS?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am working on a website and want to spin the logo 360 degrees. The website URL is http://flipped.in/JSJ/

The example code i am using is:

```css
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
     
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
     
    overflow:hidden;
 
    }  
 
.rotate:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Now, i tried replacing the class 'rotate' with the one my logo has but it does not work. Can someone help me adding the right class to this?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include your HTML as well as the CSS? It's often not helpful to future visitors if you point at an external website which might change.

Comment: `transition` is a shorthand property. So you can join `transition-duration` and `transition-property`.

Answer (score 5):

The code works as such on Chrome and Firefox. It does not work on IE, since IE implements (in modern versions) the *standard* names for the properties involved, and the code lacks a setting for the `transform` property under its standard name. Adding it makes the code work on modern browsers.

```html
<style>
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;   
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;    
    overflow:hidden;
     }  
 .rotate:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);         /* This was missing. */
} 
</style>
<img class=rotate src=
"http://flipped.in/JSJ/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/JSJ-Logo.png"
 alt="Jump Start Jonny">
```

Comment: I would keep only -webkit and -ms prefixes. -moz and -o aren't in use nowadays. see   http://caniuse.com/#search=trans

Comment: @vals, that’s a different issue, and somewhat debatable. Although browser versions that need `-moz-` or `-o-` are very rare now, it isn’t particularly useful to remove the prefixes; in new code, they might be omitted. Adding `-ms-` may be useful, since IE 9 is still in use.